# Binding events to dynamically generated content using data method of d3 js library

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to bind the click event to an element dynamically generated using the data with d3.js.

```
d3.select("#mylist").selectAll('li').data(data_arr).enter().append("li").html(
        function(d)
        {
            var element = document.createElement('div');
            element.innerHTML = '<div id="innerDiv"></div>';

            var divToClick = element.querySelector('#innerDiv');
            //Using jquery to get cross browser event binding
            $(divToClick).click(function(){
                alert('hello!');
            });



            return element.innerHTML;
       });
```

I know that the problem is that I am returning an string (innerHTML) but if I return the element it doesnt work. Any help?

(The real code is much more complex, I just copied here the important part).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer.

```
 var li_arr = d3.select("#mylist").selectAll('li').data(data_arr).enter().append("li").html(
    function(d)
    {
        var element = document.createElement('div');
        element.innerHTML = '<div id="innerDiv"></div>';
        return element.innerHTML;
   });

 li_arr.select('#innerDiv').each(function(d,i)
       {
            var mydiv = d3.select(this);
            mydiv.on('click',function(){
                alert('hello');
            });
       });
```

Answer (score 5):

A more d3 way of doing this would be

```
d3.select("#mylist").selectAll('li').data(data_arr).enter()
  .append("li")
  .append("div")
  .on("click", function() { alert("hello!"); });
```

Comment: I have not just a div inside my "li". This is just an example. I have a far more complex structure. This is not a good option.

Comment: You could try using the `.on` function on the outer element you're creating with d3. Your description neither states exactly what the problem is nor shows the exact code -- that makes it hard to figure out what you actually want to achieve and how to do it.

Comment: I want to bind click events to elements contained in the returned innerHTML .

Comment: You could either select them after they were created and then use d3's `.on` method, or change the creation of the inner HTML as I've suggested above.

Comment: As I said, modifying inner HTML creation is NOT an option (It is complex and created using jsonp services). I solved the issue iterating over the newly created HTML but I think that this is not a great solution. It should be a better way.